# Use of Gradle annotationProcessor dependency scope in Maven?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

Recently I was messing around with VSCode and configuring it to work with Java and Spring framework and I found this official [guide for setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot).

The curious thing that I'd like to share and ask about is in "[Edit the project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot#_edit-the-project)" section which contains a video on how to add dependencies. And it shows us that you can add **maven dependency with `annotationProcessor` scope**!

[image]

From [official Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) we know Maven defines 6 scopes: `compile, runtime, provided, system, test, and import`. And what I found more is that `anotationProcessor` is a dependency configuration that [could be applied in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management).

So I tried to do the same in my IntelliJ IDEA project:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
   <scope>annotationProcessor</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image]

**and it worked! - it compiles!**

So my question, I suppose, does anybody have any explanation for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The scope `annotationsProcessor` is not a valid Maven scope.

If this works and compiles, Maven probably doesn't check thoroughly enough for scopes and maybe treads this as no scope at all (i.e. compile scope).

Comment: seems like someone from VSCode Java support team is not a big Maven's fan 

Comment: @povisenko What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why they use so cleary misleading configuration in their official guide?