# Issue with Lombok not generating getters and setters or constructor and even @Data in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I utilized Spring Boot to initialize my project, and indeed, I included the Lombok dependency through Spring Boot and configured the Lombok plugin as follows:

And The IDE I use is Eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.springbootExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBoot_Example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBoot_Example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.2.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <repositories>
      
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    
  </repositories>
  
  <pluginRepositories>
      
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

However, when I use it in my entity class named department.java, it appears that Lombok is not working as expected. Even after annotating the class with @Data, @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor, and @Builder, the issue persists.

```
package com.springbootExample.SpringBoot_Example.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class department {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long departmentID;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Please add department name")
//  @Length(max = 20, min = 10)
//  @Size
//  @Email
//  @Positive
//  @Negative
//  @PositiveOrZero
//  @Future
//  @Past
//  @FutureOrPresent
    private String departmentName;
    private String departmentAdress;
    private String departmentCode;
}
```

In another configuration Java class, I'm also unable to use the getter and setter methods of the department class.

```
package com.springbootExample.SpringBoot_Example.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.springbootExample.SpringBoot_Example.entity.department;
import com.springbootExample.SpringBoot_Example.error.departmentExceptionHandling;
import com.springbootExample.SpringBoot_Example.repository.departmentRepository;

@Service
public class departmentServiceImplement implements departmentService{
    
    @Autowired
    private departmentRepository dr;

    @Override
    public department saveDepartment(department dp) {
        return dr.save(dp);
    }

    @Override
    public List<department> fetchDepartment() {
        return dr.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public department fetchDepartmentById(Long departmentID) throws departmentExceptionHandling {
        Optional<department> dpt = dr.findById(departmentID);
        
        if(!dpt.isPresent()) {
            throw new departmentExceptionHandling("Department was not found");
        }
        return dpt.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDepartmentById(Long departmentID) {
        dr.deleteById(departmentID);
        
    }

    @Override
    public department updateDepartment(Long departmentID, department dp) {
        department dep = dr.findById(departmentID).get();
        
        if(Objects.nonNull(dp.getDepartmentName()) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(dp.getDepartmentName())) {
            dep.setDepartmentName(dp.getDepartmentName());
        }
        
        if(Objects.nonNull(dp.getDepartmentCode()) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(dp.getDepartmentCode())) {
            dep.setDepartmentCode(dp.getDepartmentCode());
        }
        
        if(Objects.nonNull(dp.getDepartmentAdress()) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(dp.getDepartmentAdress())) {
            dep.setDepartmentAdress(dp.getDepartmentAdress());
        }
        
        return dr.save(dep);
    }

    @Override
    public department fetchDepartmentByName(String departmentName) {
        return departmentRepository.findByDepartmentNameIgnoreCase(departmentName);
    } 

}
```

The errors show as

```
The method getDepartmentName() is undefined for the type department
The method getDepartmentCode() is undefined for the type department
The method getDepartmentAdress() is undefined for the type department
```

[you guy can see the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eik1b.png)

I've tried several solutions, such as updating my IDE, changing Lombok plugins, and installing Lombok, but none of them have resolved the issue.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem and knows how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you showed us above _should_ be working, that is, assuming this is what you are really running to generate these errors.  That being said, you might want to avoid using the `@Data` annotation with your entity class ([see here](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/)).  Instead, explicitly use `@Getter` and `@Setter`.  Also, Java naming conventions state that Java classes should begin with an uppercase letter, so use `Department` rather than `department`.

Comment: Actually I'd like to use @Data from Lombok to simplify my code. However, it's my first time using Lombok, and I'm not entirely sure if I've made a mistake in my configuration files. After carefully checking everything, I couldn't find any issues except for one: the declared variables in my department.java class don't seem to be utilized when Lombok generates the code. The specific error message I receive is "The value of the field department.departmentAdress is not used," and this issue applies to the rest of the fields as well.

Comment: Does the use of uppercase letters in variable names have any impact when working with Lombok and Spring Boot? Everything seems to be working perfectly, except for Lombok.  but I would to give a try, will see how

Comment: try to compile/build your code from out side your IDE. if lombok is correctly configured in your project, the build from command line should work, and the error you get is simply an IDE issue. Let me know your results.

Comment: You can view the image I have just posted in the question. As shown, even when I use everything from data and builder, it still cannot generate getter, setter, and toString methods. This issue is likely due to all dependencies, plugins, or libraries already being added

Answer (score 0):

try delete the target folder and run your project again.It's work with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to install project lombok in your IDE..then only that dependency works as expected.
project lombok download link: https://projectlombok.org/download ..download this lombok then open the file after choose your IDE then click install..after installing lombok.. close your IDE then open your IDE

Comment: You can view the image I have just posted in the question. As shown, even when I use everything from data and builder, it still cannot generate getter, setter, and toString methods. This issue is likely due to all dependencies, plugins, or libraries already being added

Answer (score 0):

after spending a few days troubleshooting, I've finally discovered the reason why my project or my Eclipse IDE couldn't utilize Lombok. In order to help those who might be facing a similar issue with Lombok, I'm sharing the solution as an answer here.

so first you need to come to

```
Help --> About Eclipse IDE

if you have install Lombok plugin you will see this line --> Lombok v1.18.30 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/

if don't have or already installed but Lombok not work then you go to Installation Detail --> search on the searching bar find the Lombok then delete it
```

Then after that you take this URL

```
https://projectlombok.org/p2

go to --> help (section in eclipse) --> install new software --> you will see the "work with" --> pass the URL "https://projectlombok.org/p2" --> click add --> set name is Lombok --> click add

after that tick to the Lombok checkbox then click next --> finish --> wait for the installment completed --> restart the eclipse

then you can use Lombok already
```

below here are the image description, you can see by following step

[add Lombok with then URL I use above to install Lombok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19BG.png)

[click finish to install Lombok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuXgD.png)

Thank you so much guys, hope my problem and my solution helpful for all of you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while working on Eclipse. Even after adding the jar as a Maven dependency in the pom.xml file, Eclipse still couldn't recognize the jar. However, I was able to resolve it by following these steps:

- Make sure the jar is available in the .m2 folder after adding it to the pom.xml file.
- Open the command prompt and navigate to the location of the jar.
- Run the following command: `java -jar lombok.jar`. Replace the name with exact version
- The Lombok installation window will appear.
- Specify the location of the Eclipse installation directory. This will copy the jar to the same folder and update the eclipse.ini file with the necessary entry. This step should resolve the Lombok jar issue.
- To confirm the installation, go to Eclipse, click on "Help," then select "About IDE." Scroll to the end of the page and you should see the installation confirmation of Lombok.

Comment: This proved to be an effective solution to the problem. It worked seamlessly, and I appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

These annotations are to be executed **before** compilation. In Gradle, you need to use `annotationProcessor <lombok>` to achieve this. What you have added is the default scope, which may be `runtime` or `compile` (not sure).

For Maven, you will have to use the equivalent of `annotationProcessor`, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678057/use-of-gradle-annotationprocessor-dependency-scope-in-maven) (in the question itself).

Comment: There is no `<scope>` given for Lombok in the POM, and my understanding is the default scope would be compile.

Comment: it still same, I try your way alr, I using dependency from mvn repository also cannot work